# How to setup windows 10 to lock screen only when NOT connected to home network?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, passwords, lock-screen, geolocation

Is there a way to setup lock screen with password, BUT only when I'm not connected to my home network?

The intended use-case would be that my laptop would always be unblocked when I'm at home, but while I am away from home I would like to have the lock screen with password always activated.

I thought a good way to detect this would be if the laptop connected to my home wifi, maybe checking by gps location would also work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to setup lock screen with password, BUT only when I'm
> not connected to my home network?

For an individual machine (Windows Home or Pro), no.

The Lock Screen is not sensitive to the particular network connection, so you are best advised to use a password.

You can set the screen to go dark, leave the machine running, and not require a password when the screen lights up but that does the same thing when you are not on home network.

So best to use a password all the time.

If you are on a domain (Corporate) you can ask company IT how it is set up.